# Ubuntu server does not link external files to index.html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been developing this site for 1 week now and when I was organizing it, I started to link my index.html page to external files (like style.css and main.js) instead of including them in index.html directly. After I did that though my site does not display the colors and does not function anymore although all my syntax is correct. I say this because on my mac works, it is just in my Ubuntu server that doesn't. This is my index.html page:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text.css" href="../mystyle.css">
<title> Test  </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Welcome </h1>
<div id="testag"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I put the javascript in a file within the current directory and the style.css in a previous directory. They both do not work on my server but this same script works on my mac... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question might belong to ask Ubuntu forum, try accessing the files with direct link on server you will get some error if I am right.

Comment: The type ../css is wrong

Comment: Is your index.html in you Document root? E.g. example.com/index.html

Comment: What do you mean if it is root? I am using nginx and my root directory is where my index.html page is located and my index is index.html @Webdesigner

Comment: ../css is wrong? @Webdesigner

Comment: The linking is done entirely client side. The problem is that the URLs you have are not giving you the results you want. We have no idea why. You need to do some debugging. Look at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools. Are the URLs being requested the ones you expect? What HTTP status code do you get on the response? Not Found? Forbidden? Something else?

Comment: Oh yeah I have used the console and this is what I get: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). I am pretty sure the directory is correct, so as mentioned it could be a permission problem and there I would not know how to act... @Quentin

Comment: So the path is wrong. What makes you think it should be right? What does the structure of your file system look like? Which directory represents your DocumentRoot?

Comment: This is my root directory (this is also where index.html is): /home/fede/apps/test
My CSS file: /home/fede/apps
My Javascript file: /home/fede/apps/test/javascript
@Quentin

Comment: This is just a test server so I put the files intentionally unorganized... @Quentin

Answer (score 0):

based on your question, the corrected code would be

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../mystyle.css">
<title> Test  </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Welcome </h1>
<div id="testag"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also verify if your server has file permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have made a little mistake in the code, but that does not fix it. About the permissions how would I go about doing that?